# PostgreSQL boolean comparison

Tags: sql, postgresql, boolean

Is there a difference in the following comparisons

#1

```
where x = true
```

#2

```
where x is true
```

#3

```
where x = '1'
```

#4

```
where x
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. This is exactly the same as

   ```
   WHERE x
   ```

   It is `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL` exactly when `x` is.
2. This is the same as the first case, except when `x` is NULL, in which case it will be `FALSE`. So it is the same as

   ```
   WHERE coalesce(x, FALSE)
   ```
3. This happens to be the same as the first case, since `'1'` is interpreted as `TRUE`. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html):

   > The datatype input function for type `boolean` accepts these string representations for the “true” state:
   >
   > `true`
   > `yes`
   > `on`
   > `1`

My preferred way is the simplest:

```
WHERE x
```

Comment: "...except when x is NULL, in which case it will be FALSE" -- Shouldn't that result in UNKNOWN rather than FALSE?

Comment: @TheImpaler: in a WHERE clause "unknown" is essentially the same as "false"

Comment: I'm not sure the `WHERE` clause in `SELECT` behaves the same way as in a `CREATE INDEX`... One filters when is true, while the other when is different from "false"... not sure anymore.

Comment: @TheImpaler `x IS TRUE` will return `FALSE` if `x` is NULL. My numbering corresponds to the numbering in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Using `is` or `is not` will handle the case when the value is null. If you rely on `=`, the result of the comparison will also be `null`

```sql
select null is true as "is", null = true as "equal";
 is | equal
----+-------
 f  |
(1 row)
```

Comment: To expand on this a little: for non-null values, `x is true` and `x = true` will do the same thing.